# Rails CanCan only current user can go through Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authorization, cancan

I have a few custom rake routes and I'm trying to use CanCan for the purpose of only allowing the current user edit pages of their own account. My URL example is -> `url.com/users/4/service/edit`

I have a users controller with an action:

```
  def services
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @servicable = @user
    @services = @servicable.services
    @service = Service.new
    authorize!(:services, @user || User)
  end
```

The problem is that every time I go into the edit page I get redirected to index page. Even if I'm trying to edit my own services.

Lets say my user id is `4` and I go into `url.com/users/4/services/edit`, I get rerouted to index page. This also apples if I try using other user ids -> `url.com/users/3/services/edit`, `users/2/services/edit`, `users/63/services/edit`, and so on...

I want to be able to access my own edit page, but not others.

My route is like this:

```
resources :users do
   resources :services, :defaults => { :servicable => 'user' }
end
```

EDIT: This is my ability

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User
    elsif user.role? :business
      can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id 
    elsif user.role? :resident
      can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id 
    else
      can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id
  end
```

EDIT #2:

This is from services_controller

```
  def edit
    @service = @servicable.services.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Please ignore the routes from the top: the correct route that I'm using is like this**

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'services', :path => 'services/edit', :defaults => { :servicable => 'user' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share your Ability configuration?

Comment: Cancan does not redirect you anywhere, so I guess its problem with your routing, not with cancan. What controller does the method 'services' belongs to? What does 'edit' method looks like?

Comment: Note: you don't have to use `elsif` with cancan ability definitions. Just use separate `if/end` blocks. Much more readable. From your edit, where is `services` authorized? Check your server logs to see if you're receiving a `NOT AUTHORIZED` response before you're redirected to index.

Comment: @cthulhu I have updated my OP to show you my 'edit' method from services controller. I was going to show an 'edit' method from users_controller, but I don't think that my page is using the edit action from users_controller, unless I'm wrong?

Comment: @Damien I don't see any `NOT AUTHORIZED` in my log, but I do have an flash error that pops up in my HTML saying that `You are not authorized to access this page.` when I get redirected. And can you explain what you mean by where my `services` is authorized? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define permissions in Ability.rb like this

```
can [:update, :services], Service do |service|
  service.try(:user_id) == user.id
end
```

And you need to change `authorize!(:services, @user || User)` to `authorize!(:services, @services)` as you are checking permissions for current user to Service

Comment: its weird, it still does the same thing.it just gets re-reouted to index page

Comment: damnit! still getting a redirect to index :(

Comment: I did same steps and tested, for me forking fine. P/S use `authorize!(:services, @service` not `@services`, you can check only for one object.

Comment: hmm i  was hoping that would be the problem... but i'm still getting a redirect. You think I set up my roles incorrectly with the logged in user? I mean I did put the `can [:update,...` into the role where its not one of either `:admin`, `:business`, or `:resident`

Comment: Your role logic is correct, and user permissions are also correct, but seems like you are using `cancan` incorrectly. Please take a look cancan documentation here https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Comment: okay thanks for your help! I'll accept your answer since you validated that your side works. It might be something wrong with my programming.